# How can I constantly send data using Django WebSockets?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, websocket, django-channels

I would like to constantly send data using Django WebSockets. At this moment I try in the way shown below.

routing.py:

```
channel_routing = [
    route("websocket.connect", ws_connect),
```

consumers.py:

```
def ws_connect(message):
    message.reply_channel.send({"accept": True})
    while True:
        message.reply_channel.send({
            "text": json.dumps({
                'message': 'My response2'
            })
        })
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work properly. Obviously without `while True` it send data but only once. Any ideas how can I solve it?